# Authenticating using passport-local and PAM module

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

So I am using PAM to authenticate users in my express app. However I'm having trouble finding the right documentation and tutorial's on how to implement it and to configure sessions.

Here is the npm module for PAM called `authenticate-pam`

```
var pam = require('authenticate-pam');
pam.authenticate('username', 'password', function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log("Authenticated!");
    }
  });
```

Still on the fence on how I'm going to write this out, I know I want to implement sessions too so I am also concerned on how I would integrate that with the PAM module. Here is a rough draft of what I'm placing in the `routes/index.js` file.

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();
var pam = require('authenticate-pam');

// GET Commands ==========
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Login', layout: 'base-layouts/login-layout.hbs'});
});

// POST Commands ==========
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var usernameCaptured = req.body.username;
  var passwordCaputured = req.body.password;
  console.log('Username: ' + usernameCaptured); // For debuging
  console.log('Password: ' + passwordCaputured); // For debuging
  pam.authenticate(usernameCaptured, passwordCaptured, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Not Authenticated");
      //Send to login page with error.
    }
    else {
      console.log("Authenticated!");
      res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Dashboard', layout: 'base-layouts/dashboard-layout.hbs'});
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

That's as far as I've gotten for auth. As for sessions this is what I have placed in the `app.js` (main file) of my app.

```
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').BasicStrategy;
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    //This is what I got from the documentation. It's not fully integrated with the PAM module
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id); //Think this integrates with a DB, but I can just sync usernames with a flat file.
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      done(err, user);
    });
```

Looks pretty simple, but there's a not lot of tutorials and it's hard to tell which ones I can use. Some of them don't even explain what they are doing. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... if you get a SIGTERM you will have to run as root. Not sure what the solution for that is.

```
var passport            = require('passport');
var Strategy            = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var pam                 = require('authenticate-pam');

module.exports = function(passport){

  // =====================================
  // Custom Strategy =====================
  // =====================================
  passport.use('pam', new Strategy({
      usernameField : 'username',
      passwordField : 'password',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) {
      pam.authenticate(username, password, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', err));
        }else{
          done(null, username);
        }
      }, {serviceName: 'login', remoteHost: 'localhost'});
    })
  );

  // =====================================
  // PASSPORT SERIALIZE ==================
  // =====================================
  passport.serializeUser(function(username, done) {
        done(null, username);
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
        done(null, username);
  });

};
```